# XAMPP - Novo Conceito de Segurança

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Estou com um probleminha com o XAMPP, não estou conseguindo permitir o acesso do PHP MyAdmin ao celular.
Já vi tutos na Net mas nada resolveu.
obs: O PC é 64Bits, mas só achei a versão de 32 Bits para baixar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração do http-xampp.conf

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp" </IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
# LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll" LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll" LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php </FilesMatch> <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source </FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php" </IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps </IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/" <Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files> </Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch> </Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php7_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig </Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var    </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory> </IfModule>
```

Comment: Tente mudar o "Require local" para "Require all granted" no trecho:  "Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"...."Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network

Comment: @WilliamPereira - Em que local?

Comment: Está no arquivo que vc colocou. Tem um trecho que inicia em Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin"> ..... embaixo tem "Require local" muda para "Require all granted", isso irá liberar o acesso externo no diretorio do phpmyadmin

Comment: Faz salva e reinicia o apache do xampp

Comment: @WilliamPereira - Estás a funcionar, muito obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: Beleza! Que bom q ajudou